# If U is a finite-dimensional subspace of W, prove the orthogonal complement of W is a subspace of the orthogonal complement of U

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

If U is a finite-dimensional subspace of W, prove the orthogonal complement of W is a subspace of the orthogonal complement of U. Not sure how I start with this proof. Can someone help?

Comment: Spell out the definitions. $v\in W^\perp \iff \forall x\in W\colon \ldots$

Comment: Let $v \in W^{\bot}$. This means that it is orthogonal to every vector of $W$. In particular, it is orthogonal to every vector of $U$ (because $U$ is a subset of $W$). End of the proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.